# Element is not in intersection of A and B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a statement that $x \notin (A \cap B)$.  I know that this implies $(x \notin A$ or $x \notin B)$, as it makes sense intuitively.

My question is, by definition of  intersection of sets, wouldn't it become $(x\notin A $ and $x \notin B)$?? I know it's wrong, but just going by definitions, why is this incorrect?

Comment: The intersection is amde of the elements that are in **both** $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thus, if $x \notin (A \cap B)$ means that is not in one of them.

Comment: This is closely related to [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), one of which states the complement of an intersection is the *union* of two complements.

Comment: If I am not rich and famous then I am either not rich or not famous. I don't have to be both not rich and not famous.

Comment: I guess my question is, I know what the correct expression is, and it makes sense, but using the DEFINITION of intersection $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, wouldn't $x \notin A \cap B \rightarrow x \notin A and x \notin B$? What is the error in my thinking here? should $x \notin (A \cap B)$ be viewed as $x \in NOT(A \cap B)$?

Comment: was a satisfactory answer ever provided? the question is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

An element $x$ can be in one of the sets, but not the other:

If $A =\{a,b,c\}, B = \{a,b\}$, $c \notin (A\cap B)$ and $c \notin B$, but $c \in A$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see this is to use truth tables.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 x \in A & x \in B & x \in A\cap B \\ \hline
T&T&T\\ 
T&F&F\\
F&T&F\\
F&F&F\\
\end{array}
$