# Why does $ x \in (A \cap B)^c \implies x \in A^c \cup B^c $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is true:

$$ \boxed{ x \in (A \cap B)^c \implies x \in A^c \cup B^c }$$

Notation - here $S^c$ is the complement of the set $S$.

---

**Question:** *Why* is this true?

I know it is true by constructing a Venn diagram to show that it is.

However I would like to see a step-by-step argument based on the fundamental definitions of sets and the union/intersection/complement operators.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148225/element-is-not-in-intersection-of-a-and-b) also asks the same question but the comments and answers fail to provide a solution to the specific question of *why*.

---

**Further research:**

Understanding Analysis, Second Edition, by the well respected Stephen Abbott, has an exercise and an official solution by the author. To quote the step I am not understanding:

> If $x \in (A \cap B)^c$ then $x \notin (A \cap B)$. But this implies
> $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$.

Why does this imply $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$ ? This is not obvious to me.

Again, to clarify, I can draw Venn diagrams to confirm the truth but I would like to see logical steps based on fundamental definitions or axions if possible.

Attempting to think about this in plain English with a real-world example to see if it helps .. doesn't seem to help:

> If it is not summer and hot, then it is not summer or not hot.

Comment: The law that $(A \cap B)^\mathsf{c} = A^\mathsf{c} \cup B^\mathsf{c}$ is one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), in their set-theoretic expression. The other is $(A \cup B)^\mathsf{c} = A^\mathsf{c} \cap B^\mathsf{c}$. These laws correspond to their equivalents in logic: $\neg(P \land Q) \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$ and $\neg(P \lor Q) \equiv \neg P \land \neg Q$. PrincessEev's answer explains the intuition behind this well.

Comment: @Penelope think of it this way: the intersection of A and B are the elements that are simultaneously in A and in B; ie it is the set of elements that they have in common. The complement of that is the set of elements that do NOT belong to both, ie the elements that belong to A and not B, or those that belong to B but not A. $B^c$ are precisely the elements of the first type and $A^c$ are the elements of the second type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were true that $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ and $x\in B$. That is,
$$
x \in A \cap B \iff (x \in A \land x \in B)
$$
Well, $x \not \in A \cap B$, so we consider the negation:
$$
x \not \in A \cap B \iff \neg (x \in A \cap B) \iff \neg (x \in A \land x \in B)
$$
Then we ask: what is the negation of a logical "and" statement, say $\neg (P \land Q)$? It is, as be shown in a way of your preference (e.g. truth tables) that
$$
\neg (P \land Q) \equiv (\neg P) \lor (\neg Q)
$$
Hence
$$
x \not \in A \cap B \iff \underbrace{x \not \in A}_{\neg (x \in A)} \lor \underbrace{x \not \in B}_{\neg (x \in B)}
$$

> If the shape is not blue **and** circular, then either it is not blue, or it is not circular. (Or both. The logical "or" is inclusive.)

Comment: hi @PrincessEev - thanks for this clear explanation. The key step for me is $\neg (P \land Q) \equiv (\neg P) \lor (\neg Q)$ .. my feeling is that this is taken for granted, or generally accepted because it is so easy to prove using truth tables. Can I ask, amongst professional mathematicians, is this just accepted as a common fact?

Comment: As stated, you can prove it from the logical definitions of "and", "or", and "negation", and a truth table, as [here](https://i.imgur.com/v4zuERP.png). It certainly is accepted as common fact, both because it is provably true from the axioms, and because it lines up entirely with how we'd expect it to work in common language.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be the universe of discourse where $A = \{x\in U \mid p(x)\}$ and $B = \{x\in U \mid q(x)\}$. According to the definitions as well as the logical operators properties involved, one concludes the desired result:
\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)^{c} & = \{x\in U \mid x\not\in A\cap B\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U \mid \neg(p(x)\wedge q(x))\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U \mid \neg p(x)\vee\neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U \mid \neg p(x)\}\cup\{x\in U \mid \neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = A^{c}\cup B^{c}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x$ is not in $A\cap B$. Then $x$ is not in $A$ or $x$ is not in $B$. That is, $x$ is in $A^c$ or in $B^c$. Thus, $x\in A^c\cup B^c$.

Comment: this is concise and helpful too.